# Javascript .replace() replace all occurrences of /

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string that contains `</custom-tag>` , how can I use replace to find all occurrences of this tag in a string and replace it with "" , for example `mystr.replace(/</constant>/g,"")` will not work.

Comment: What you have should work if you escape the slash as `/<\/constant>/g`

Comment: you need to escape you /

Comment: Please open your browser's developer console. You should get a helpful error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` so that it isn't interpreted as the end of the regex.

```
mystr.replace(/<\/constant>/g, "")
```

Of course, if your search is a constant expression, as it is here, you can use the following technique to perform a global replace without regular expressions:

```
mystr.split("</constant>").join("")
```

Comment: thx alot i really hate regex , so i didnt know how to escape it.

Answer (score 3):

```
mystr.replace(/<\/constant>/g,"");
```

this should do it